# Why is Entity Framework Core using SqlConnection on Azure?

Tags: c#, postgresql, azure, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm creating an application using PostgreSQL database.

I'm using the `AddDbContext.UseNpgsql()` methods to work with it :

`Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDbContext<DbModel>(options => 
    options.UseNpgsql(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("connectionStringName"))
```

When I'm starting the application on my computer (Windows 11), it works. I'm able to connect to my PostgreSQL database, perform migrations, CRUD actions and else.

But when I'm trying to deploy it on an Azure App Service (running Linux) I get the following error :

> Application startup exception
> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
> at Microsoft.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.CreateDbConnection()
> ...

Even if I'm using the `UseNpgsql()` method, it seems like on the App Service only, Entity Framework Core is still trying to use SQL Server instead of PostgreSQL, and it cannot recognize the keyword "port".

But why? How can I tell it to use the correct Npgsql provider?

**UPDATE 1**
I've changed my local connection string to make it throws an error, here is the stack trace I have in local when a keyword is not supported :

> System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: azerty (Parameter 'keyword')    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetProperty(String keyword)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object
> value)    at
> System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
> value)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String
> connectionString)    at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings()
> at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)    at
> Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlRelationalConnection.CreateDbConnection()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.get_DbConnection()

In local, it uses the correct provider. Do I have to change a setting on the Azure App Service ?

Comment: Have you verified that the connection string your app is reading is correct in case when it's deployed to Azure?

Comment: @marc_s yes, it's the right connection string

Comment: I've updated my question with a test of providers

Comment: I'd double-check that you're running the right version of the application on Azure. If the application does UseNpgsql, you shouldn't be seeing SqlClient.

Comment: @ShayRojansky yes, you were right. My deployment pipeline was broken for a while and I just discovered it right now. Sorry for the time loss, and thanks for your help !